# Running Hoogle Locally

Tags: haskell, hoogle

I want to run `hoogle` on a project of mine. I successfully generated the hoogle database (a file with `.hoo` extension) from my project.
But when I run the server locally, hoogle cannot find any of the functions or types that are defined in my project.
It can find some of the prelude functions such as `map`, but none of the functions that are defined in my project.
`hoogle dump my-project.hoo` dumps the content with no error.
I also moved `my-project.hoo` to `~/.cabal/share/x86_64-osx-ghc-7.8.4/hoogle-4.2.38/databases` where all the `.hoo` files reside. No success again.
`-verbose` switch also does not output any useful information.
Any suggestion is appreciated.

**Edit:**

Thanks to `mhuesch`'s suggestion, I was able to get the search results. Although, the returned results are not linked to the local hackage documents. **Something that I couldn't find anywhere on the web is that the hoogle server looks for a file called `default.hoo` in the current directory.**

**Edit 2:**

If you, like me, have 5000+ databases (*i.e.*, `.hoo` files) you may get a "too many open files" error when combining them. The trick is simple: run `hoogle combine x*.hoo -o=parts/x.hoo` for all `x='a' ... 'z'` and then run `hoogle combine *.hoo -o=default.hoo` in the parts folder.

**Edit 3:**

If you want to link your hoogle search results with local hackage documentation,
use `hoogle convert --doc='absolute-path-to-your-doc' your-package-hoogle-doc.txt default.hoo`.
I couldn't get relative path working.

Comment: AFAIK you have to run `hoogle combine` to get your database in there - sadly all online docs are deadlinked right now and I cannot find the details - I am sure someone will help ASAP

Comment: The [Ganeti](http://code.google.com/p/ganeti/) project has a [repository](http://git.ganeti.org/?p=ganeti-hoogle.git) with a slack role that automates setting up a Hoogle web server from scratch which indexes all the Haskell code of the project. Perhaps it could be helpful to you. (Disclaimer: I'm involved in the project.)

Answer (score 3):

Hoogle searches the current directory (where the command `hoogle` is run) for a database called 'default.hoo', so if you rename your database to that it should find it.

To add it to the database in your cabal directory, I believe this should work (taken from http://newartisans.com/2012/09/running-a-fully-local-hoogle/):

```
cd {...path to hoogle databases dir...}
mv default.hoo default.hoo-prev
hoogle combine *.hoo
```

**Edit:** (in response on `Oxy`'s edits)

My knowledge of `default.hoo` comes from [here](https://github.com/gilligan/hoobuddy). It seems to doesn't seem to be very well know.

hoobuddy (the above linked project), while cool, doesn't seem to address what you want. I think the key to that is in the help of hoogle data

```
$ hoogle data --help
...
-l --local[=FILEPATH]  Use local documentation if available
...
```

I haven't done it myself so I am not sure. The author of [this writeup](http://newartisans.com/2012/09/running-a-fully-local-hoogle/) achieved local documentation linking by compiling hoogle from source and adding his local docs directory. I *think* that you can avoid that by using hoogle data.

Comment: Great! It actually somehow solved the problem. Now, my functions show up in the search results, but they are not linked to local hackage documentation. How can I link to local documents of the packages?